# ASIHTTP: Upload UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, asihttprequest, http-put

Can someone please tell me how I can use an ASIHTTPRequest object in Objective-c to upload an UIImage object? Do I need to convert it to an NSData object?

(This is for an avatar upload url)

```
E.g. 

UIImage *toUpload = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"]

URL: "http://www.example.com/api/users/avatar/upload?access_token=12345"
RequestType: PUT
```

Answer (score 14):

Heres an example using ASIFormRequest that will also attempt to compress the image to given maximum size

```
    //Compress the image
CGFloat compression = 0.9f;
CGFloat maxCompression = 0.1f;
int maxFileSize = 250*1024;

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, compression);

while ([imageData length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
{
    compression -= 0.1;
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, compression);
}

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:whereYourServerEndPointIs.com]];

[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"someFileName.jpeg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"uploadedImage"];
```

Comment: Great answer. I've got this one bookmarked for a project I'm working on with C#

Comment: Great answer. The while loop design is really useful.

Comment: Any reason to use `addData` over `setData`?